# refresh the mysql table value in php

Tags: php, mysql

For a long time I have been trying to solve one problem. After the user logs in, the php script retrieves all information from its mysql line.

```
...
if ($rezultat = @$polaczenie->query(

        sprintf("SELECT * FROM kontabankowe WHERE login = '%s' AND haslo = '%s'",
            mysqli_real_escape_string($polaczenie, $login),
            mysqli_real_escape_string($polaczenie, $haslo)))) {
        $ilu_userow = $rezultat->num_rows;

        if ($ilu_userow > 0) {
            $_SESSION['zalogowany'] = true;

            $wiersz = $rezultat->fetch_assoc();

            $_SESSION['id'] = $wiersz['id'];
            $_SESSION['imie'] = $wiersz['imie'];
            $_SESSION['nazwisko'] = $wiersz['nazwisko'];
            $_SESSION['login'] = $wiersz['login'];
            $_SESSION['haslo'] = $wiersz['haslo'];
            $_SESSION['nrkonta'] = $wiersz['nrkonta'];
            $_SESSION['pieniadze'] = $wiersz['pieniadze'];

            $rezultat->free_result();
...
```

Then, I display this data in my application, in this way:

```
<div id="pieniadze">
    <span>Dostępne środki: <?php echo $_SESSION['pieniadze'] ?></span> PLN
</div>
```

But in later actions in the application, the value `$_SESSION['pieniadze']`
 in mysql changes to a different value, **but** in the above place, **the previous value is displayed**.

In my opinion, in the place where I update this value, it should re-download the value of mysql and convert it to a variable `$_SESSION['pieniadze']`, but I do not know how to do it. maybe there are better solutions?

Comment: If you need up to date info on every page load, pull it from the database every time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the values to be updated, do the MYSQL query at each time, so it will refresh the value. It will impact a bit in performance, but is the only way.

So you might save the user id in a session variable and then retrieve the rest of the data in all requests.

Session variables store information in PHP for the user, MYSQL is not directly involved.

Answer (score 0):

have you assigned the following values? of the kind

> $ login = $ _POST ['login']; >
>
> $ haslo = $ _POST ['haslo'];

if you did it check with if possible result exists with an 'echo'

if ($ ilu_userow> 0) {

```
echo 'exist'
```

....